# Do you have to call glfwSwapInterval(1) in an OpenGL program?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I ran my program twice. The first time with glfwSwapInterval(1) and everything was just fine.
The second time without glfwSwapInterval(1) and it was using 100% of my CPU.

My Question: Is this normal and do I really have to call glfwSwapInterval(1) in order for my program to run  properly.

The code:

```
glfwInit();

long window = glfwCreateWindow(1200, 800, "OpenGL", 0, 0);
glfwShowWindow(window);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
GL.createCapabilities();

glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwPollEvents();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
glfwTerminate();
```

Comment: Well, do you want your `while` loop to run as fast as possible and produce frames that the user will never see, or do you want to be sure every frame you produce is sent to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sync your rendering loop to the refresh rate of the monitor you have to call it. The default behaviour is rendering as many frames as possible.

Comment: But whenever I decide not to call it. The CPU usage jumps to 100%. Is this normal?

Comment: @TymoTymo  Because your program is doing so little and not synchronised with the refresh rate it is essentially in a hard-loop producing no observable effect.

Comment: @TymoTymo: "The CPU usage jumps to 100%. Is this normal?" Yes. If you run code, that code will always use 100% of some CPU core in the instant it is running, and the only way to _not_ use as much CPU time as available is by calling into some kernel function which eventually results in telling the OS scheduler to not schedule your thread - be it some explicit sleep function, or some other kernel function which has put your thread to sleep and wake it up later on some sort of event.

Comment: @TymoTymo If you dont want vsync, but limit CPU usage, you can add `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000/fps)` in your render loop.

Answer (score 4):

The [GLFW documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__context.html#ga6d4e0cdf151b5e579bd67f13202994ed) mentions: "`glfwSwapInterval` is not called during context creation, leaving the swap interval set to whatever is the default on that platform."

So essentially, whether or not synchronization is enabled depends on your platform. For example, on my machine the default seems to be the opposite from what you were seeing.

In most cases, you'll want to call `glfwSwapInterval(1)` to enable sync, but if you have a reason to disable it (for example, if you're comparing shader performance) you can also call `glfwSwapInterval(0)`.